# Command in supervisord failing 'stdout_log and system command'

Tags: linux, logging, system-calls, supervisord

I have a c++ executable which I monitor using supervisord. And I made supervisord as startup process. When I reboot, supervisord and my executable are working fine (functionally). And Stdout_log file is created in tmp (which is also fine). But the log file is empty.

And In my executable I am running few bash scripts which I do it using system(), but It is also failing.

So I have two issues

1. log file is empty
2. system() is failing

I can related these issues to some permission, but no clue to fix it. Looking for some suggestion

Thanks

Comment: A log file can easily be empty when your binary is not producing output on `stdout`.. have you checked if there is any `stderr` output instead?

Comment: Also, *how* are your system() runs of your bash scripts failing?

Comment: even Stderr is empty. Please note that I am getting all log file If I launch supervisord by myself (i.e. UID is me and not root)

Comment: And what happens if you launch your *executable* as root?

Comment: When it is in root, 'stdout_log and system command' are not working (system() returns -1)

Comment: Conclusion: don't run your executable as root. Either configure a `[supervisord]` `user` parameter, or configure a `user` parameter for your executable in it's `[program:x]` section.

Comment: I want root user privilege, since i am having few listener and bound to the socket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your executable cannot be run as root itself, run it as as non-privileged user instead.

Either configure *all* of supervisord to run as another user by setting the `[supervisord]` `user` option:

```
[supervisord]
user = wwwdata
```

or set a `user` parameter for your executable in it's `[program:x]` section:

```
[program:yourprogram]
user = wwwdata
```

Comment: I want root user privilege, since i am having few listener and bound to the socket

Comment: Then you need to fix your executable to work under root first; in any case this is not a supervisord problem.